# Select users from table that have at least one entry in diffierent table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to select users from a user table that have at least one relating entry in another table. Probably my join approach is totally wrong but that is what I was trying and should give you an idea of the structure:

```
SELECT users.`id`, users.`email`, users.`username`, users.`status`, users.`date_reg`
FROM dir_editors as users
JOIN dir_links as links ON (links.`id_editor` = users.`id`)
WHERE COUNT(links.`id_editor`) > 1
```

So the goal is to get all these user data from user that have at least one link entry in the `dir_links` table where the `id_editor` is the field in the dir_links table.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Just remove the `where` criteria -- the `join` should do what you're looking for.

Comment: No need for WHERE at all. Inner JOIN assures matches in both tables.

Comment: If you're going to use JOIN, just remember to use a group by clause, and group it by users.id, otherwise you'll get repeated records of the user, for each record that he has on dir_links.
Another option is to create a where clause and remove the JOIN. It would be something like WHERE (select count(1) from dir_links where id_editor = users.id) > 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT users.`id`, users.`email`, users.`username`, users.`status`, users.`date_reg`
 FROM dir_editors as users
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dir_links as links WHERE links.`id_editor` = users.`id`)
```

Comment: Just a note: This solution doesn't require to use `DISTINCT`, while you would need it, if you use a `JOIN`. So this solution isn't only very close to a pseudo code, but will probably also performe better.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.`id`, users.`email`, users.`username`, users.`status`, users.`date_reg`
FROM dir_editors as users
JOIN dir_links as links ON (links.`id_editor` = users.`id`)
```

Remove this `WHERE COUNT(links.`id_editor`) > 1` because this imposing condition.

[INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

An INNER JOIN selects the records that are found in both tables, depending on a key that you put in your ON statement:

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, users.username, users.status, users.date_reg
FROM dir_editors AS users
INNER JOIN dir_links as links
ON links.id_editor = users.id
```